# How to fetch a video from an api in flutter and display it on my screen

Tags: flutter, api

i'm trying to fetch a video from an endpoint and display it on a flutter a flutter Listview but i can't figure out how to do it.

Here is what i've done so far.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyTest extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchVideo() async {
    // var result = await http.get(apiUrl);
    final result = await http.get(Uri.parse('myUrlStaysHere'));
    return json.decode(result.body)['response'];
  }

  String _info(dynamic video){
    return video['name'];
  } 
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(title: Text('Testiing'),),
      body: Container(
        child:  FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: fetchVideo(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             if(snapshot.hasData){
               return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget> [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              child: (here is where i want a video to be),),
                            title:Text(_info(snapshot.data[index])),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
               );
             }else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          } ,
        ),

      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my endpoint

```json
{
   "response":[
      {
         "title":"Panama - Canada",
         "videos":[
            {
               "embed":"<div ><iframe src='https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/embeded;'><\/iframe><\/div>"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can only fetch the title for now but i cant figure out how to get the video and place it in the specified container.
Can somebody help please

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the video url or download the video file, then you can use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) lib. Else, if you want to show a Youtube video, then use [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). But in this cases you need to change your API

Comment: Its not a youtube video , and i can't actually pass the url coz  it does not directly point to the video as you can see from the above response

Comment: If you have only a embed video in html, you can use [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) to render the content, or [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)